# Php Regex close open tag on line break

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have html code like this :

```
<li>some text
more text

<li>some other text
any more text
```

I would like to close the list items. An Item shall be closed on a line break.
The result shall look like this:

```
<li>some text<li>
more text

<li>some other text<li>
any more text
```

This is my regex, which does not work:

```
preg_replace("/<li>+(.*?)+/ig","\\2</li>", $o );
```

It returns nothing instead of:

```
<li>some text<li>
more text

<li>some other text<li>
any more text
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will take all in the li-line and the `\K` will clear the match and set *cursor* to the right point:

```
<li>.*\K
```

Then replace with it:

```
</li>
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fS3xR8/1)

It is due the `.` don't match `\n`.

---

With effectiveness:

```
<li>.*(?:(?<!<\/li>)(?=\s*\n))\K
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fS3xR8/3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to implement your problem with preg_replace

[Regex live](https://regex101.com/r/tP0dE1/1)

```
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('/<li>(.*)/', '<li>$1</li>', '<li>some text
more text', -1, $count);
```